# match a xml tag and replace its value

Tags: xml, regex, perl

I am trying to replace the header tag `<h*>` with
 `<center><h*>.....</h*></center>` the problem I am facing is the `<center>` tag are not wrapped around when I have a header tag which starts at one line and ends at some other line for eg.

```
<h3> Spotting the
    Pileated
    HummingBird in
    the wild </h3>
```

I want to replace the header tags with `<center><h*> .. </h*></center>` tags.

this is what I am trying its working good it the a header tag starts and ends at the same line but not for multiple lines.

```
while (<>){
           $_ =~ s/^\<h(.)>\s*(.*)\s*<\/h(.)>/<center><h$1>$2<\/h$3><\/center>/g;
       print $_;
}
```

Comment: Don't do that with regular expressions, please use a XML parser for this, it's better for the future.

Comment: there is one special condition that only header tags that are given at the starting of the line should be considered for the replacement and not the one which have some leading spaces between them. That is why I thought I should go with regex. Mine one is working but not for those tags which starts and ends at different lines.

Answer (score 0):

Well I must say using XML Parser would ease your life further. But finding a regex should not be that hard if you consider applying multine regex. I tested with following piece of code and it worked.

```
my $str = '<h3> Spotting the
    Pileated
    HummingBird in
    the wild </h3>';

$str =~ s/(<h\d>[\n\s\w]*<\/h\d>)/<center>$1<\/center>/mg;
                                                       ^
                                                       |------ for multiline regex   
print $str;
```

As you can see using `/m` will let you write an expression that matches over multiple lines. Hope that will help.

`[\n\s\w]*` is here just based on your given sample text. You may need to modify it to meet your original requirement.